# SQL query by dates

Tags: sql, nested, subquery

I've got a problem with a SQL query in which I would like to search for contracts which got terminated in a period. This is my sample data, so I would like to get contract1 for 201803 and contract2 for 201804 - two contracts which ended in first for months; what query should I use if this data is from a table `rcontracts`? Thanks

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query after replacing with your column names.

```
SELECT t1.dt + 1, 
       t1.c 
FROM   rcontracts t1 
       LEFT JOIN rcontracts t2 
              ON t1.c = t2.c 
                 AND t1.dt + 1 = t2.dt 
WHERE  t2.c IS NULL 
       AND t1.dt < (SELECT Max(dt) 
                    FROM   rcontracts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `not exists`?

```
select rc.*
from rcontracts rc
where not exists (select 1
                  from rcontracts rc2
                  where rc2.contract1 = rc2.contract2 and
                        rc2.yyyymm > 201803
                 );
```

Or aggregation?

```
select rc.contract
from rcontracts rc
group by rc.contract
having max(rc.yyyymm) < 201804;
```